# How to sum numerator and denominator of a fraction?

Tags: arithmetic, summation

I want to do sum over this.  Can apply the summation to top and bottom separately?

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{-a(x_i-\mu)^2}{x_i}$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}-a(x_i-\mu)^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$

Is this correct?

Where can I find the rules to summations of a division, product, or addition?

Edit:
I want to solve for y, 
$$\frac{5}{y}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{-a(x_i-\mu)^2}{x_i}$$
$$\frac{y}{5}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{-a(x_i-\mu)^2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: $\frac13+\frac23=\frac33$, not $\frac36$

Comment: simple and elegant, thanks!

Comment: If it looks like it's too simple to work, it probably doesn't.  Could you cancel the $6$s in $\frac{16}{64} = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Remember the rule: in mathematics, *Nothing is True* **unless** there’s a reason for it to be true.

Comment: The part in the edit is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example $ \frac{3 + 2}{1 + 1} = \frac{5}{2} \neq 5 = \frac{3}{1} + \frac{2}{1} $. There are no basic rules for division or product. Of cource, $ \sum a_n + b_n = \sum a_n + \sum b_n $ which follows from definition.

One trick to use with products though is that $ \ln \prod a_n = \sum \ln a_n $.

Comment: $ \ln \prod a_i = \sum \ln a_i $  where $a_i= \frac{1}{x_i}$ is ok?

Comment: Yes, $ a_i $ can be anything other than $ 0 $. If there is some $ a_i = 0 $, then the product is $ 0 $.

Comment: Hi, I edit original question, is this true?

Answer (score 3):

As the example in the comment shows nicely, **no** - Another simple example shows why this can't work: $$\frac 12 + \frac 12 \neq \frac 24 = \frac 12$$

Next: You might want to visit Wikipedia's entry for [**Summation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities), which includes a nice list of *valid manipulations* that hold for sums.

Comment: @Amzoti, lol, are you serious?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you *can* do which might be helpful is, assuming $x_i>0$ for all $i$,  $$\frac{-a(x_i-\mu)^2}{x_i}=\frac{-a(x_i-\mu)^2}{(\sqrt{x_i})^2}=-a\left(\sqrt{x_i}-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{x_i}}\right)^2$$

Comment: I added "edit" section, how to solve for y?